# Why linker does not find my template static member?

Tags: c++, templates, methods

I have a class declared with:

in `unit.h`:

```
class unit {
    ...
    template<typename T>
    static
    void *marshal(void *buff, const std::string &name, T value);
    ...
};
```

in `unit.cpp`:

```
template<typename T>
void *unit::marshal(void *buff, const std::string &name, T value) {
    ...
    return buff;
}
```

Somewhere else I try to call it:

```
   ...
    unsigned char buffer[100], *end = nullptr;
    end = (unsigned char *) unit::marshal(buffer, "Chimes1_Volume", 222);
   ...
```

compiler is happy, but linker bombs with:

```
 undefined reference to `void* AW::unit::marshal<int>(void*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: previously I had a `friend` function, instead of the `static` method, but I got the same problem.

**UPDATE**:
If I move the implementation in the header file, inside class declaration, it works, but I need to understand what's wrong with the split `.h`/`.cpp` implementation.

working `unit.h` contains:

```
class unit {
    ...
    template<typename T>
    static
    void *marshal(void *buff, const std::string &name, T value); {
        ...
        return buff;
    }
    ...
};
```

body was copy&paste, of course.

I am pretty sure I copied the definitions right, but...

Comment: the function definition/impl is in the header file correct?

Comment: Is the definition of `unit::marshal` in a header or cpp file ?

Comment: @RichardCritten: I updated OP to be more explicit.